# I am not able to download Silverlight runtime on IPad.?

Tags: silverlight

I am working on Ipad and version is 5.1 but I am not able to download the Silverlight runtime to run my application.

So does anybody have any idea why it will not allow it to download?

It says safari is not able to download this file.

Thank you..!!

Comment: It's not supported. You're out of luck I'm afraid!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers can be found:

http://forums.silverlight.net/t/158649.aspx/1